# How to correctly use MongoDB with multiple threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb

I'm using the mongo-java-driver-3.0.0 library to proceed the insertion of many data in my instance of MongoDB. The problem is that when I try to use multiple threads (simulating multiple users), after some insertions the following error happens:

```
INFORMAÇÕES: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:816}] to
  localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed. Exception in thread
  "user_4" com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: 
  Prematurely reached end of stream
```

The code where I'm calling the instance and proceeding the insertions is:

```
public static FachadaMongo getInstancia() {
    if (instancia == null) {
        instancia = new FachadaMongo();
    }
    return instancia;
}

public MongoDatabase getDB(String HOST, String PORT, String DB_NAME) {
    MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
    //build the connection options  
    builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60000);//set the max wait time in (ms) 60 segundos
    MongoClientOptions opts = builder.build();

    int port = Integer.parseInt(PORT);
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(HOST, port), opts);
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(DB_NAME);
    return db;
}

public MongoCollection getColecao(String HOST, String PORT, String DB_NAME, String colecao) {
    MongoCollection col = FachadaMongo.getInstancia().getDB(HOST, PORT, DB_NAME).getCollection(colecao);
    return col;
}

public void insert(String HOST, String PORT, String DB_NAME, Document documento) {
    this.getColecao(HOST, PORT, DB_NAME, "documentos").insertOne(documento);
}
```

Even if I use this code with only one thread, the same error appears after a while. With multiple threads, the error comes faster.
If someone could help me, I'd be thankful, my final work on college depends on that.

Comment: And yes, I've looked for a lot of troubleshooting about Closed Connection and End of Stream. But none of the solutions I've tried works.

Answer (score 2):

After some more tests, I could find the reason of the problem. 
In the getDB method, I was creating a new connection for each insertion in the database. Multiplying the number of connections by the number of clients, I was "overconnecting" my database.
I fixed it by replacing the line

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(HOST, port), opts);
```

With the line:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient;
```

in the beginning of the class, and the line:

```
if (mongoClient == null) mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(HOST, port), opts);
```

in the same place that the other I removed.

Now it's working well.